# Why Jinni but not Genie?

Tags: character, legacies

In *Legacies* S01E10, we see the first Jinni/Genie in the Vampire Diary universe but Ablah gets so furious when Lizzie calls her Genie and always corrects her or shows agitation. But why? Is there any difference between these two names for this character?

Answer (score -1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn):

> Jinn (Arabic: الجن‎, al-jinn), also Romanized as djinn or Anglicized as genies (with the more broad meaning of spirits or demons, depending on source), are supernatural creatures in early pre-Islamic Arabian and later Islamic mythology and theology.

I think this Ablah character just doesn't like the Anglicized version.

Comment: This answer seesm to be based *entirely* on an opinion. What we are looking for is a **referenced** answer.